# R reads European format numerical values as factors

Tags: r, categorical-data

In R3.1.2, I have uploaded a dataset. My numerical values, however, reads as Factors. By searching online, I found that this code should change my values from factors to numerical:

```
as.numeric(as.character(athene))
```

But when typing in this line, the following message occurs:

> 'NAs introduced by coercion'

and a lot of NAs occur on my screen. The same happens when I specify the specific factor that I would like to change

```
(as.numeric(as.character(MAG)).
```

When I look at my dataframe, it has not changed, and still looks like it did before. Nothing has happened:

```
str(athene)
```

> 'data.frame':   72920 obs. of  17 variables:
>
> $ MAG: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
>
> $ PCR: int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>
> $ LO : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>
> $ WAT: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>
> $ SVE: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>
> $ ARA: int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
>
> $ GRA: int  0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
>
> $ FOR: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>
> $ B13: Factor w/ 233 levels "100,00","101,00",..: 1 233 13 15 5 10 8 6 7 14 ...
>
> $ B12: Factor w/ 1538 levels "1000,00","1001,00",..: 959 960 1013 1024 977 993 974 966 966 1011 ...
>
> $ MTP: Factor w/ 198 levels "0,00","1,00",..: 137 179 36 133 122 122 110 113 197 110 ...
>
> $ MB6: Factor w/ 264 levels "-1,00","-10,00",..: 238 238 240 236 240 233 234 236 236 251 ...
>
> $ URB: int  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>
> $ BI1: int  12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
>
> $ MHF: int  11 9 7 7 7 8 9 10 0 8 ...
>
> $ BI4: int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
>
> $ ALT: int  1 1 3 4 1 4 1 1 1 1 ...

If someone has any hits as to what I am doing wrong with regards to changing my factorial values into numerical ones, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When I try the following, another error occurs:
 > as.numeric(levels(athene))[as.integer(athene)]

Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R does not understand that we Europeans use "," as a decimal separator. Change all "," to "." using `gsub()` before coercing to `numeric`:

```
> B13 <- factor(rep(c("100,00","101,00","102,00"),1:3))
> B13
[1] 100,00 101,00 101,00 102,00 102,00 102,00
Levels: 100,00 101,00 102,00
> as.numeric(gsub(",",".",as.character(B13)))
[1] 100 101 101 102 102 102
```

Comment: or possibly use `read.csv2`, if your data are in the correct format.